# Calling TensorBoard from Keras to inspect diagnostics

Tags: python-3.x, keras, tensorboard

I am trying to use TensorBoard with Keras and I follow the instructions in this short tutorial: http://fizzylogic.nl/2017/05/08/monitor-progress-of-your-keras-based-neural-network-using-tensorboard/

My code is:

```
from time import time

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard


# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir="logs/{}".format(time()))

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, y, validation_split = 0.3, epochs=30, callbacks = [tensorboard])
```

The code is executed without any problem.

Following the advice of the tutorial:

> Monitoring progress Now that you have a tensorboard instance hooked up
>   you can start to monitor the program by executing the following
>   command in a separate terminal:
>
> `tensorboard --logdir=logs/`

I open a terminal and execute the aforementioned command.  This is what I get:

```
(base) C:\Users\Alienware\Documents>tensorboard --logdir=logs/
2019-01-07 22:02:56.109894: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
TensorBoard 1.8.0 at http://ALIENWARE-PC:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
W0107 22:04:55.763794 Thread-1 application.py:274] path /[[_dataImageSrc]] not found, sending 404
W0107 22:04:55.779416 Thread-1 application.py:274] path /[[_imageURL]] not found, sending 404
```

I then open the webpage. This is what I see:

[image]

How can I sort this out?

Answer (score 0):

It needs to the exact folder that the data is saved into. You format `log_dir="logs/{}".format(time())` the directory using the current which is obviously not the same directory as `logs/`. By default the logs directory is `keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir='./logs',...)`.

You would need to either remove the time formatting or start `tensorboard` on the correct directory.

Comment: @ nuric: That is interesting, thank you!  Let's say I follow your second suggestion 'start tensorboard on the correct directory'.  I need two things to execute this advice: a) Find which is the correct directory, b) start tensorboard on the correct directory.  Could you help me do a) and b) correctly?

Comment: a) depends on where you are running your model terminal from, logs will be in that directory as well b) you will need to `cd` (change directory) to the same directory as the model terminal and run `tensorboard` (hint it's probably not Documents)

Comment: OK, finally I got it.  Thank you a lot!